# Splash screen using MVP design pattern in Android

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I am doing some research about MVP design pattern in Android and got a question about splash screen. The app that i am developing with MVP design pattern does not have particular behaviors on the activity of splash screen.

In this situation, should I consider using MVP design pattern in building the activity of splash screen or just making in a simple way without MVP pattern on the activity of splash screen?

Could you give me some suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MVP, MVVM, MVC** all these design patterns are used to maintain the code in a systematic way and for the separations of things. Since your **Splash screen** is not going to have a lot of code it is not a good idea to create a presenter class and implement it. I would say just skip that for that activity. And follow design pattern for other activities

Comment: I was thinking the same way as your suggestion but wasn't sure enough. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [OOPS **SOLID** principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID),

**Open–closed principle**

> Software entities ... should be open for extension, but closed for modification.

Even if your Splash Screen does not have particular behaviors, you should consider using MVP.

Also, you should consider using your special theme instead of creating a layout for it.

Create a **drawable** named `backgroundDrwable.xml` with following content (change color and drawable as needed):

```
<item android:drawable="@color/mycolor" />

<item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/app_logo"
        android:gravity="center" />

</item>
```

Create new theme in **styles.xml**

```
 <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/backgroundDrwable</item>
</style>
```

You don't need provide any layout in `onCreate` method, this theme will render a background with your **app_logo** in center. Yes, Don't Forget to assign your theme to your `SplashActivity` in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and solution. I will consider both.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create splash screen without messing with your code?

**Create a style:**

```
<style name="splashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@mipmap/app_icon</item>
</style>
```

**Add this style to the activity in the manifest**

```
 <activity android:name=".Activity"
        android:theme="@style/splashScreenTheme">
```

Comment: Yeah, i also think its a good idea not to mess with code like your comment.